# Error in fitdistr package for using fitdist in for loop

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I am running the below code, i.e to save the AIC values for negative binomial distribution in a vector.

```
max_nbinom_aic <-data.frame(NBINOM_AIC=numeric(0))
 for(i in 1:336) {
     a <- max_samples[,i]
     d <- fitdist(a,distr ="nbinom") 
 max_nbinom_aic <- rbind(max_nbinom_aic,d$aic)
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Error in fitdist(a, distr = "nbinom") : 
>     the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
>                   with the error code 100
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In sqrt(diag(varcovar)) : NaNs produced
>   2: In sqrt(1/diag(V)) : NaNs produced
>   3: In cov2cor(varcovar) :
>     diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful

Also the output only contains 62 values, whereas I am expecting 336 values as I have 336 sets of distribution.

Comment: your code is not reproducible.

Comment: Have a look here how to ask a question that others will be able to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example